# jQuery doesn't amend html as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to amend a price through JQuery. When I add thecode to the console all seems to be ok, but the html doesn't change. Also when I call the `console.log(newPrc)` it says "newPrc" not defined. My code is:

```js
(function($) {
  Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t) {
    var n = this,
      c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c,
      d = d == undefined ? "." : d,
      t = t == undefined ? "," : t,
      s = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
      i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "",
      j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
    return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
  };

  $(document).ready(function() {

    oldPrc = jQuery('body.checkout-delivery .basket__totals #grand-total-price .price').html();
    newPrc = oldPrc.replace('<span class="currency">£</span>', '');
    newPrc = newPrc.split(',');
    newPrc = newPrc[0] + newPrc[1];
    newPrc = parseInt(newPrc) + 39;
    newPrc = '<span class="currency mtI">£</span>' + newPrc;
    jQuery('body.checkout-delivery .basket__totals #grand-total-price .price:has(.currency:not(.mtI))').html(newPrc);
  });


})(jQuery);
```

Comment: is oldPrc and newPrc defined anywhere else? If not you'll need to define them with 'var' which would explain the console error.

Comment: where are you putting console.log(newPrc)?

Comment: I am putting it to the console to preview the value of newPrc

Comment: @john when? after the code runs? when you're on a breakpoint inside the code?

Comment: After I execute the code I run the console log

Comment: What I want to do is get the oldPrice and add 39 to it with new variable called newPrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I've added jQuery and the appropriate demo markup to the snippet it appears to add 39 (well not really as 39 plus 4.99 is not 43) to the original price as you intended and display the result in the HTML:

```js
(function($) {
  Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t) {
    var n = this,
      c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c,
      d = d == undefined ? "." : d,
      t = t == undefined ? "," : t,
      s = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
      i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "",
      j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
    return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
  };

  $(document).ready(function() {

    oldPrc = jQuery('body.checkout-delivery .basket__totals #grand-total-price .price').html();
    newPrc = oldPrc.replace('<span class="currency">£</span>', '');
    newPrc = newPrc.split(',');
    newPrc = newPrc[0] + newPrc[1];
    newPrc = parseInt(newPrc) + 39;
    newPrc = '<span class="currency mtI">£</span>' + newPrc;
    jQuery('body.checkout-delivery .basket__totals #grand-total-price .price:has(.currency:not(.mtI))').html(newPrc);
  });


})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="checkout-delivery">
  <div class="basket__totals">
    <div id="grand-total-price">
      <div class="price"><span class="currency">£</span>4.99</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Does your markup look like the markup above?